# iteration of a loop function in a list

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, phylogeny

I deleted the old question since it was not clear.

I would like to ask how we can interate a loop function for a list

I created one example by using the `phytools` package

```
# a set of trees
List <- list(tree1= pbtree(n=3, tip.label = c("Pycnonotus_simplex", "Pycnonotus_brunneus", "Blythipicus_rubiginosus")),
          tree2 = pbtree(n=3, tip.label = c("Blythipicus_rubiginosus", "Pycnonotus_erythropthalmos", "Orthotomus_atrogularis"))) 

class(List) <- "multiPhylo"

# a vector of species would be added
spp <- c("Pycnonotus_sp.02", "Pycnonotus_sp.08")
```

I will add randomly spp to one tree by `add.species.to.genus`

```
for (i in 1:length(spp)){
    tree1 <- add.species.to.genus(tree1, spp [i], where = "random")
}
```

I hope now my question is clear. Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

**Updated**

Hi guys,

I already solved my problem since when I use the fuction `add.species.to.genus` that results in the limited precision in the edge lengths of the tree.

By using `force.ultrametric` fucntion will deal with

```
for (i in 1:length(List)){
  tree[[i]] <- List[[i]]
  for (j in 1:length(spp)){
    tree[[i]] <- force.ultrametric(tree[[i]])
    tree[[i]] <- add.species.to.genus(tree[[i]], spp[j], where = "random")
  }
}
```

Comment: no! not clear `Error in pbtree(n = 20) : could not find function "pbtree"`

Comment: oh, thank you very much. I already added the package that I am using `phytools`

Comment: and what is `species`?

Comment: Not clear still

Comment: I made a new list. Please check it